# How do I process a set of images for a neural network?

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing

So this is my first time branching away from the mnist data set so i'm wondering how I should go about processing the images.

Currently, I have a folder filled with images and a list of labels. I'd like to read the images into an array that will be fed into my CNN.

Here is how I think this should be done:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import array
for i in image_list:
  img = Image.open("i")
  training_set.append(array(img))
```

I'm not sure if this is the most effective way to do this. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please check the documentation and examples for whatever framework you're using.  Also, please notice that you're not doing any "processing" on these files -- all you're doing is opening them and making a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following to read image data. You'll probably want the image represented as a 1D array - but you'll need to read the docs of your CNN.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

data = []
for path in image_list:

    # This will be a 3D array
    img = np.asarray(Image.open(path).convert('RGB'))

    # Flatten before appending
    img_flat = img.reshape(img.size)

    data.append(img_flat)
```